# Indicator matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In matlab, I have a double datatype variable named **Label** with dimension **1211 x 1**.

I would like to create a **IndicatorMatrix**(6 columns) such that if a row in the **Label** variable is **34** then the corresponding row in the **IndicatorMatrix** should be **0 0 1 1 0 0**.

I mean 1 @ 3 and 4th column of Indicator matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `x` be the 1211x1 matrix (Label), and let `im` (IndicatorMatrix) be the matrix you wish to create. Do:

```
h = size(x,1);
im = [zeros(h, 2), repmat(x == 34, 1, 2), zeros(h, 2)];
```

This creates a matrix which is a horizontal concatentation of a zero matrix with 2 columns and height h, then a boolean matrix of x == 34 (which has 1 where x was 34, and zero in other places) repeated 2 times horizontally and once vertically, and then again another zero matrix.

Note that in your case we could have replaces h by 1211, but I tried to write more generic code.